# Cuts on complete binary trees

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

Claim : Suppose we have a complete binary tree of height $h$. We introduce a cut to partition this tree into two sets of vertices of size $x$ and $2^h - 1 - x$ for some $x$. For any $x$, we define the optimal cut size of to be the minimum number of edges crossing from one side of the cut to the other side. For all values of $x$, we see what's the optimal cut size, and take the maximum of these values. Let's call that to be $m$. Then, there is no $x$ for any $h$ such that the optimal cut size for both $x$ and $x+1$ vertices is $m$.

Note : I don't know if this claim is true.

Can anyone prove this?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the complete tree with 3 vertices. Clearly when $x = 1$, the optimal cut is 1. However, when $x=2$, the optimal cut will just be the same, but with the partitions reversed, so the claim is false.

Comment: Is there case other than when the maximum size cut is found at x = $2^{n-1}-1$ ?

Comment: I believe so. I also think I've determined the exact value of the optimal cut, but the proof turned out to be harder than I was expecting so it's incomplete. I might finish it at some point and if I do I'll post it here.

Comment: Oh. Thanks! Do post your proof when available.

Comment: Have you finished your proof? Even if not complete, can you share what work you have done?

Comment: Ah I totally dropped this. I didn't end up finishing it. I believe that the size of the optimal cut for $x$ vertices in a binary tree of size n will be $1 + \min\limits_k |2^k - x|$. The reason (which I was unable to prove) is that I believe that there is always a minimal partition that is a complete (in the sense given here: http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~sheard/course/Cs163/Doc/FullvsComplete.html) subtree of the larger tree.